# How to setup and use Kafka-Connect-HDFS in HDP 2.4

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use kafka-connect-hdfs on hortonworks 2.4. Can you please help me with the steps i need to follow to setup in HDP env.

Answer (score 4):

Other than building Kafka Connect HDFS from source, you can download and extract Confluent Platform's TAR.GZ files on your Hadoop nodes. That doesn't mean you are "installing Confluent"

Then you can `cd /path/to/confluent-x.y.z/`

And run Kafka Connect from there.

```
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties
```

If that is working for you, then in order to run `connect-distributed` (the recommended way to run Kafka Connect), you need to download the same thing on the rest of the machines you want to run Kafka Connect on.

Comment: Hi there, i've tried your suggestion by running kafka connect. And an error occured. Would you mind to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526864/kafka-to-hdfs-sink-missing-required-configuration-confluent-topic-bootstrap-ser . Thank you so much

Comment: This answer does not use `Hdfs3SinkConnector`